# Actualizar el estado en React Native

Tags: react-native

Tengo el siguiente componente que hace parte de un todo **list**
Deseo actualizar el estado cuando el usuario añade una nueva tarea.
Sin embargo, me aparece el siguiente error:

> "TypeError:Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable intance".

Este es mi código:

```
this.state = {
      textInputValue: "",

      todos: [
        { text: "buy me a Frontend masters Course", key: 1 },
        { text: "buy me frontend books", key: 2 },
        { text: "buy me a new chair", key: 3 }
      ]
    };    


    addNote() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      todos: [
        ...prevState,
        {
          text: this.state.textInputValue,
          key: (this.state.todos.length + 1).toString
        }
      ]
    }));
  }
```

Alguien podría darme una ayuda?, gracias

Comment: Hola Christian, creo que deberías cambiar la línea donde tienes el `...prevState` por `...prevState.todos`

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir un elemento en un **list** sin modificarlo tienes que hacer una copia superficial. Es lo que hace  "spread".

```
const myList = [1, 2]
const myListExtended = [...myList, 3] // [1, 2, 3]
```

Lo mismo con los diccionarios:

```
const myDict = {a: 1, b: 2}
const myDictExtended = {...myDict, c: 3} // {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Pero no puedes mezclarlos:

```
const myDict = {a: 1, b: 2}
const myListExtended = [...myDict, 3] // Error
```

Es lo que occurió aquí.

`prevState` es un diccionario como `this.state` y no puedes hacer el **spread** en list.

Tú tienes un error en tu código. Tienes que poner solo un elemento de `prevState.todos` en lugar de `prevState` en `setState`.